# Efficient generic Python memoize

Tags: python, memoization

I have a generic Python memoizer:

```
cache = {}

def memoize(f): 
    """Memoize any function."""

    def decorated(*args):
        key = (f, str(args))
        result = cache.get(key, None)
        if result is None:
            result = f(*args)
            cache[key] = result
        return result

    return decorated
```

It works, but I'm not happy with it, because sometimes it's not efficient. Recently, I used it with a function that takes lists as arguments, and apparently making keys with whole lists slowed everything down. What is the best way to do that? (i.e., to efficiently compute keys, whatever the args, and however long or complex they are)

I guess the question is really about how you would efficiently produce keys from the args and the function for a generic memoizer - I have observed in one program that poor keys (too expensive to produce) had a significant impact on the runtime. My prog was taking 45s with 'str(args)', but I could reduce that to 3s with handcrafted keys. Unfortunately, the handcrafted keys are specific to this prog, but I want a fast memoizer where I won't have to roll out specific, handcrafted keys for the cache each time.

Comment: *and apparently making keys with whole lists slowed everything down*. No it won't. `dict` storage is just as efficient whatever your key, and lookups are O(1). Something completely different is wrong with your app, I am afraid.

Comment: There are many recipes and modules for that on [Pypi](http://pypi.python.org/). Also Python 3.2+ ships with `functools.lru_cache`

Comment: Is that really so? Lists aren't considered hashable in Python, and `dict` storage keys must be hashable. Maybe the OP actually has a point.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work with list, so I actually used str on args. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a way that isn't at least O(n) for lists and other mutable containers (at least if you want to differentiate such containers by value, not by identity). To distinguish two n-element containers, you need to consider every element (even for hashing, though tuples and strings can and do cache their hash). Why do you need memoization with unhashable arguments?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The point is that how you make the keys can be efficient or not. Please note that I have changed my original post to indicate that I'm going through 'str'. I think that is what is not efficient. And the question remains: if you want a generic memoize, how do you _efficiently_ produce keys for the elements in your cache, no matter what args you'll receive, what their types will be or how long they will be. Going through 'str' is one way, and apparently it can handle many situations, but I believe it's not efficient.

Comment: Side note: If you just *believe* that, you should profile it before making assumptions (use `cProfile`, by grouping calls by caller you can check how much time is spent in that specific `str` call). It's possible that the conversion to string kills performance, but other causes are also possible.

Comment: So I tried with this memoize, and another memoize that makes keys with only 2 ints, no other difference in the program. The difference is 3s vs 45s. In retrospect, it seems pretty clear that making strings from long lists would take O(length of list). I verified that the keys in the cache are indeed looong strings (> 1000 chars). I thought that would explain it and didn't look further.

Comment: You are saying lists but you really mean tuples and that difference is very fundamental in python.

Comment: No I mean lists. I know the difference between a tuple and a list. I specifically create those lists with: v = list(np.random.randint(1,100,(n))). Always funny when someone thinks they know what you mean better than you :-)

Comment: But the function argument 'args' is by definition a tuple!

Comment: What I mean is that inside the args, I have lists.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I should have read the comments more carefully.

Comment: @JBernardo: `functools.lru_cache` and most of the modules and recipes on PyPI and ActiveState either require hashable inputs, or require consistent `repr` (which is usually a stricter requirement, and one that can't be checked properly as well…), so they won't help for `list` input. But you're right that it's probably worth basing a `list`-memoizer on something that's been thought through in all of the other ways, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @abarnert Are there languages that provide out-of-the-box, built-in memoization for all functions?

Answer (score 7):

First, if you're pretty sure that `O(N)` hashing is reasonable and necessary here, and you just want to speed things up with a faster algorithm than `hash(str(x))`, try this:

```
def hash_seq(iterable):
    result = hash(type(iterable))
    for element in iterable:
        result ^= hash(element)
    return result
```

Of course this won't work for possibly-deep sequences, but there's an obvious way around that:

```
def hash_seq(iterable):
    result = hash(type(iterable))
    for element in iterable:
        try:
            result ^= hash(element)
        except TypeError:
            result ^= hash_seq(element)
    return result
```

I don't think sure this is a good-enough hash algorithm, because it will return the same value for different permutations of the same list. But I am pretty sure that no good-enough hash algorithm will be much faster. At least if it's written in C or Cython, which you'll probably ultimately want to do if this is the direction you're going.

Also, it's worth noting that this will be correct in many cases where `str` (or `marshal`) will not—for example, if your `list` may have some mutable element whose `repr` involves its `id` rather than its value. However, it's still not correct in all cases. In particular, it assumes that "iterates the same elements" means "equal" for any iterable type, which obviously isn't guaranteed to be true. False negatives aren't a huge deal, but false positives are (e.g., two `dict`s with the same keys but different values may spuriously compare equal and share a memo).

Also, it uses no extra space, instead of O(N) with a rather large multiplier.

At any rate, it's worth trying this first, and only then deciding whether it's worth analyzing for good-enough-ness and tweaking for micro-optimizations.

Here's a trivial Cython version of the shallow implementation:

```
def test_cy_xor(iterable):
    cdef int result = hash(type(iterable))
    cdef int h
    for element in iterable:
        h = hash(element)
        result ^= h
    return result
```

From a quick test, the pure Python implementation is pretty slow (as you'd expect, with all that Python looping, compared to the C looping in `str` and `marshal`), but the Cython version wins easily:

```
    test_str(    3):  0.015475
test_marshal(    3):  0.008852
    test_xor(    3):  0.016770
 test_cy_xor(    3):  0.004613
    test_str(10000):  8.633486
test_marshal(10000):  2.735319
    test_xor(10000): 24.895457
 test_cy_xor(10000):  0.716340
```

Just iterating the sequence in Cython and doing nothing (which is effectively just N calls to `PyIter_Next` and some refcounting, so you're not going to do much better in native C) is 70% of the same time as `test_cy_xor`. You can presumably make it faster by requiring an actual sequence instead of an iterable, and even more so by requiring a `list`, although either way it might require writing explicit C rather than Cython to get the benefits.

Anyway, how do we fix the ordering problem? The obvious Python solution is to hash `(i, element)` instead of `element`, but all that tuple manipulation slows down the Cython version up to 12x. The standard solution is to multiply by some number between each xor. But while you're at it, it's worth trying to get the values to spread out nicely for short sequences, small `int` elements, and other very common edge cases. Picking the right numbers is tricky, so… I just borrowed everything from [`tuple`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/tupleobject.c). Here's the complete test.

_hashtest.pyx:

```
cdef _test_xor(seq):
    cdef long result = 0x345678
    cdef long mult = 1000003
    cdef long h
    cdef long l = 0
    try:
        l = len(seq)
    except TypeError:
        # NOTE: This probably means very short non-len-able sequences
        # will not be spread as well as they should, but I'm not
        # sure what else to do.
        l = 100
    for element in seq:
        try:
            h = hash(element)
        except TypeError:
            h = _test_xor(element)
        result ^= h
        result *= mult
        mult += 82520 + l + l
    result += 97531
    return result

def test_xor(seq):
    return _test_xor(seq) ^ hash(type(seq))
```

hashtest.py:

```
import marshal
import random
import timeit
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import _hashtest

def test_str(seq):
    return hash(str(seq))

def test_marshal(seq):
    return hash(marshal.dumps(seq))

def test_cy_xor(seq):
    return _hashtest.test_xor(seq)

# This one is so slow that I don't bother to test it...
def test_xor(seq):
    result = hash(type(seq))
    for i, element in enumerate(seq):
        try:
            result ^= hash((i, element))
        except TypeError:
            result ^= hash(i, hash_seq(element))
    return result

smalltest = [1,2,3]
bigtest = [random.randint(10000, 20000) for _ in range(10000)]

def run():
    for seq in smalltest, bigtest:
        for f in test_str, test_marshal, test_cy_xor:
            print('%16s(%5d): %9f' % (f.func_name, len(seq),
                                      timeit.timeit(lambda: f(seq), number=10000)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Output:

```
    test_str(    3):  0.014489
test_marshal(    3):  0.008746
 test_cy_xor(    3):  0.004686
    test_str(10000):  8.563252
test_marshal(10000):  2.744564
 test_cy_xor(10000):  0.904398
```

Here are some potential ways to make this faster:

- If you have lots of deep sequences, instead of using `try` around `hash`, call `PyObject_Hash` and check for -1.
- If you know you have a sequence (or, even better, specifically a `list`), instead of just an iterable, `PySequence_ITEM` (or `PyList_GET_ITEM`) is probably going to be faster than the `PyIter_Next` implicitly used above.

In either case, once you start calling C API calls, it's usually easier to drop Cython and just write the function in C. (You can still use Cython to write a trivial wrapper around that C function, instead of manually coding up the extension module.) And at that point, just borrow the `tuplehash` code directly instead of reimplementing the same algorithm.

If you're looking for a way to avoid the `O(N)` in the first place, that's just not possible. If you look at how [`tuple.__hash__`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/tupleobject.c), [`frozenset.__hash__`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/setobject.c), and [`ImmutableSet.__hash__`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/sets.py) work (the last one is pure Python and very readable, by the way), they all take `O(N)`. However, they *also* all cache the hash values. So, if you're frequently hashing the *same* `tuple` (rather than non-identical-but-equal ones), it approaches constant time. (It's `O(N/M)`, where `M` is the number of times you call with each `tuple`.)

If you can assume that your `list` objects never mutate between calls, you can obviously do the same thing, e.g., with a `dict` mapping `id` to `hash` as an external cache. But in general, that obviously isn't a reasonable assumption. (If your `list` objects never mutate, it would be easier to just switch to `tuple` objects and not bother with all this complexity.)

But you can wrap up your `list` objects in a subclass that adds a cached hash value member (or slot), and invalidates the cache whenever it gets a mutating call (`append`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, etc.). Then your `hash_seq` can check for that.

The end result is the same correctness and performance as with `tuple`s: amortized `O(N/M)`, except that for `tuple` `M` is the number of times you call with each identical `tuple`, while for `list` it's the number of times you call with each identical `list` without mutating in between.

Comment: +1 Interesting and detailed.  With using your `hash_seq`, would it be possible for 2 different input sequences to result in the same output value?

Comment: The pure Python version gives 87s on my actual prog, v 45s originally and 15s with marshall.dumps. I have not tried Cython yet, but I'm very curious to try it.

Comment: @Gerrat: Of course, it's _always_ possible—you can't hash a potentially infinite number of values into a single `int` without collision. The problem with my first implementation is that it happens even in some reasonable use cases—e.g., `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 2, 1]` will hash the same! The second version (with the `*= mult` bit) fixes that, but I still wouldn't swear that it's a "good enough" hash function.

Comment: @Frank: Do you know how to use Cython's [`pyximport`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#pyximport) for simple testing? If not, if you have any questions, ask me.

Comment: @abarnert I tried to implement the Cython code you have above. I managed to compile it. It seems to be very fast, but I got something wrong, because the result of my prog is wrong. I think I get collisions somehow, which makes the caching wrong. Do you have a complete version with values for the primes that you could post? (PS: this is my first time ever using Cython - but I love it already!)

Comment: @abarnert I followed the tutorial on the Cython website, wrote a .pyx file and compiled it. It works, but if there is an even simpler way to do that (inlining Cython in Python?), I'd be happy to use that.

Comment: @abarnert PS: the results I'm seeing are "too good to be true", I need the cache behavior to be correct before I can look at performance. But it seems very promising. Plus mixing C/C++ and Python is a dream come true for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21845/discussion-between-frank-and-abarnert)

Comment: I guess I missed you in chat, so… I've put the complete, hopefully-correct test code in the answer. Meanwhile, see [cython-inline](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-cython-inline) in the docs, but I usually find `pyximport` simpler for testing (and doing proper `distutils` better for real projects).

Answer (score 3):

You could try a couple of things:

Using marshal.dumps instead of str might be slightly faster (at least on my machine):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("marshal.dumps([1,2,3])","import marshal", number=10000)
0.008287056301007567
>>> timeit.timeit("str([1,2,3])",number=10000)
0.01709315717356219
```

Also, if your functions are expensive to compute, and could possibly return None themselves, then your memoizing function will be re-computing them each time (I'm possibly reaching here, but without knowing more I can only guess).
Incorporating these 2 things gives:

```
import marshal
cache = {}

def memoize(f): 
    """Memoize any function."""

    def decorated(*args):
        key = (f, marshal.dumps(args))
        if key in cache:
            return cache[key]

        cache[key] = f(*args)
        return cache[key]

    return decorated
```

Comment: Thanks! Rewriting the code didn't do anything significant. Using marshal.dumps brought the runtime from 45s to 15s. - Can we do better?

Comment: You could check out Raymond Hettinger's various memoizing decorators on active state.  I think he's responsible for the LRU cache on Python 3.2.  There may be other things you can do as well, but possibly not "generically".  I see you've revised your question to specify that you want something generic.  ...in that case, Raymond's stuff is likely as good as it gets.

Comment: Testing on len=3 seems a bit unfair—but I repeated your tests with various different lengths; marshall is about twice as fast as str for most mid-range values, and a lot faster for very small and very large lists (in the latter case, I'd guess that's because of memory usage or allocations?), so this is definitely a winner. As for whether we can do better, see my post—but it likely depends on whether you want to stay in pure Python.

Comment: My 45s result was with the lists I have in the program, which can be  > 1000 chars.